# What's the most efficient way to build a URL from an object with an unknowable number of properties?

Tags: javascript, function, object, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to write a set of reusable functions to abstract a bunch of SharePoint's REST API web services which is probably unnecessary context but I always feel kind of weird framing these questions.

Anyway.  The endpoints all take parameters and I've decided to feed the operation that does the AJAX call and handles the return a Javascript object (if there's a better way to do this, I'm still learning, totally open to suggestions) called "Options" that has as its properties the parameters, like so:

```
ApiHelper.prototype.getListData = function(options){
    //Set the base endpoint Url.
    var executeUrl = "/web/lists/getByTitle('"+options.list+"')";

    //Determine if the URI will have parameters.
    var params;
    var paramList = [];

    if(options.select.length || options.filter.length || options.expand.length || options.top.length){
        params = true;
        paramList.push(options.select,options.filter,options.expand,options.top);
    }else{
        params = false;
    }

    //The first two ops are super basic and don't take parameters, so I collapse them into a single line.
    if(options.op == 'All'){return this.execute(executeUrl).then(function(data){if(data.d){return data.d;}else{throw "Something bad happened..."}});
    }else if(options.op == 'Id'){executeUrl+='/Id';return this.execute(executeUrl).then(function(data){if(data.d){return data.d.Id;}else{throw "Something bad happened..."}});
    }else if(options.op == 'Forms' || options.op == 'Views' || options.op == 'WorkflowAssociations'){
        executeUrl+=options.op;
        return this.execute(executeUrl).then(function(data){
        if(data.d && data.d.results){
            return new QueryResults(data.d.results);
        } else {
            throw "Something bad happened...";
        }
    });
    }else{
        if(params){
        //No idea...
    }else{
        //If we're doing Items but without params...
        executeUrl+='/items';
    }

    return this.execute(executeUrl).then(function(data){
        if(data.d && data.d.results){
            return new QueryResults(data.d.results);
        } else {
            throw "Something bad happened...";
        }
    });
}
```

For ease of use on the user, I wanted to make the parameters optional.  Originally, I was doing something like this with the parameters:

```
if(typeof options.select === 'undefined'){options.select = '';}
if(typeof options.filter === 'undefined'){options.filter = '';}
if(typeof options.expand === 'undefined'){options.expand = '';}
if(typeof options.top === 'undefined'){options.top = '10000';}
```

And then constructing the URL with the parameters attached anyway, just empty.  That... works, but it seems inelegant and with SharePoint, you know, I can never be sure it will work.  So, my goal here is to look at the options object and if, for example, there's a select statement, then append $select=[whatever], but if not, then don't.  Same for filter, expand, and top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) all the parts of the URL query

```
function param(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    return [key, obj[key]].map(encodeURIComponent).join('=');
  }).join('&');
}
```

You may also look at jQuery's [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/). It does basically the same and supports arrays. You can find the source [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/91850ecbbe04ad8f5d89dc050aa1d9002047c435/src/serialize.js#L55).

Comment: So, both answers were great, but I ended up using $.param, that was the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function getProps(obj){
    var str='';
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(str)str+='&';
        else str='?';
        str+=prop+'='+obj[prop];
    }
    return str;
}
```

I hope this will help.